# На диске недостаточно свободного места для выполнения этой операции

Tags: windows

Поставил убунту на жестак, поделив его, затем удалил из за желания перекинуть на ссд.
На жестком диске осталось пространство не распеределеное которое не могу сейчас объединить выдает ошибку. Гуглил!!!!))) Использовал сторонний софт безрезультатно, может кто подскажет с проблемой?[image: введите сюда описание изображения], [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я хочу объединить не распеределенный раздел 161 гб с островным (Дистры)

Comment: Недавно, хорошо и просто, правда не быстро, отработало приложение DiskGenius, на винде.

Comment: Я пользовался бесплатным Paragon Partition Manager, всё супер.

Comment: `Gparted Live` тоже не помогает?

Answer (score 0):

Объединить можно только последовательные разделы или место на диске. Удалите 2-ой раздел на диске 0 или переместите его в конец диска, потом расширьте 1-ый за счёт свободного пространства.